# Why is a different font or font-size being used when generating a PDF?

Tags: asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports-2010

We've got an older ASP.NET app that has a page in it that generates some reports using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 2010, and then displays that in a page. (It actually overwrites what's in the page.) The odd thing is that even though we've modified the .rpt files, when we put them into the ASP.NET project and print them, either the font size is smaller or the font family has changed. (I'm not good at identifying font families by looking at them, so I don't know which is happening.) Anyway, it generates these .PDF files which get displayed to the user, and either the font size is smaller or the font family has changed, and I can't figure out how it's happening.  For example, the font family we've chosen is Arial and the minimum font size is 10. But when I print it out the resultant report is smaller. Why is that and what, if anything, can we do about it?

Comment: Are you recompiling the project after modifying the RPT files?

Comment: Yes I am recompiling the project.

Comment: Are the font sizes correct when the PDF prints?

Comment: They don't look it, when printed from the ASP.NET website, even using PDF/Adobe Viewer.

Comment: Any chance you have any code and/or the RPT file you can share?

Comment: The only code we have is formulas associated with handling things like when a field is null. Things like this:

    if IsNull({ASIMedical.LiverDisease}) then "No"
    else if {ASIMedical.LiverDisease} = 0 then "No"
    else "Yes"

I can't imagine that would effect the font size.

Comment: What about the ASP code that generates the Crystal Report?